# Error with NLTK packages

Tags: python, pip, nltk

I am trying to download nltk packages.

```
nltk.download()
```

Then, `all`, `all-corpora` and `book` are all red in colour. When I download `all`, it downloads, after a while says `Done downloading all` but the red is not turning green.

Am I missing out any step here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLTK data out of date - Python 3.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183618/nltk-data-out-of-date-python-3-4)

Comment: Someone else just asked the same question; see there for answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's working, either give it some time or close the download window then reopen with `nltk.download()`.

To ensure the [download](http://www.nltk.org/data.html) completed properly you can run:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown.words()
['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', ...]
```